# What does "I'm really burned out on 4 cups of coffee" mean?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context

Context:

> I'm getting a new coffee machine, and I am probably bad at figuring out the amount of instant Coffee needed for a cup. So **im really burned out on 4 cups of coffee**.

Comment: Avoid asking what a text or utterance means. Interpretation requests (criticism, discussion, analysis, and divining the author’s intent) are out of scope and may be removed. This applies to all English texts and utterances, including (but not limited to) song lyrics, poetry, and legal documents. See: “[What topics can I ask about here? - Help Center](/help/on-topic)”. If there is an unstated specific concern, such as “What does (word) mean in context?” or “How does (grammar or punctuation rule) apply in context?” ask that question instead.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I don't quite get it.

So okay, the person doesn't know how much coffee grounds to use in the coffee machine. We're supposed to get the idea that he's using a radically wrong amount of coffee grounds. So he's making his coffee either extremely strong or extremely weak.

So I THINK he means that he's making his coffee so strong that with 4 cups he has gotten an "overdose" of caffeine and is totally burned out.

But 4 cups of coffee is rather a lot to have, anyway. Many people would be burned out with 4 cups of normal-strength coffee.